# How do syntax and coordinate calculations work with the Tikz library `calc`?

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax

I'd like to annotate an image in LaTeX using Ti*k*z. I'm rather new to Ti*k*z, so I have been following a [tutorial](https://latexdraw.com/how-to-annotate-an-image-in-latex/) which breaks it down quite nicely.

In the tutorial they add an image to a node and then set a custom coordinate space to make annotation easier. So far, so good.
In my special case, I'm working with two images side by side, which I'd like to have in the same coordinate space. However, they don't have the same height.
To get the scaling for the x-axis to work, I figured out to use `|-` to get the vertical intersection of the south east corner of the right image with the x-axis.

So, my question:
This code works, but Why? And what is the correct way of doing it if I'm exploiting a bug or something here...
As you can see, there is an opened parenthesis, that is not closed and if I were to close it, like this, it would break:

```
\begin{scope}[x={($.1*(img2.east |- (0,0))$)}, ...
                                         ^
```

How are the coordinates calculated, and how does the syntax actually work in this case (with the parenthesis and `$`)?
I can't find anything about this particular issue anywhere, and I haven't found any good documentation for the syntax in general.

I'm happy with any input on this.

---

My code and compiled image:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[above right, inner sep=0] (img1) at (0,0) {
            \includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{example-image}
        };
        \node[below right, inner sep=0] (img2) at ($(img1.north east)$) {
            \includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{example-image}
        };
        
        % Annotations
        \begin{scope}[x={($.1*(img2.east |- (0,0)$)}, y={($.1*(img1.north west)$)}]
            \draw[red, step=1] (0,0) grid (10,10);
            
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code as it is in the tutorial if you place both images in one node:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
% Include the image in a node
\node [
    above right,
    inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image}\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}};
 
% Create scope with normalized axes
\begin{scope}[
x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]
 
% Grid
    \draw[lightgray,step=1] (image.south west) grid (image.north east);
 
% Axes' labels
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,10} { \node [below] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
    \foreach \y in {0,1,...,10} { \node [left] at (0,\y) {\y};}
 
% Labels
    \node[circle,fill=green] at (7.25,6.75){\small 2};
 
    \draw[latex-, very thick,green] (2.5,1) -- ++(-0.5,0)
        node[left,black,fill=white]{\small Voltage source};
 
    \draw[stealth-, very thick,green] (5,1.75) -- ++(0.5,-0.5)
        node[right,black,fill=white]{\small Dspace card};
 
    \draw[very thick,green] (0.5,2.5) rectangle (4,9.5) 
        node[below left,black,fill=green]{\small 1};
 
    \draw[latex-, very thick,green] (5.5,4) edge (5.5,5.5)
        (5.75,4.5) -- (5.5,5.5)
        node[above,black,fill=white]{\small R-L load};
\end{scope}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I did not know you could do that, thanks. As I understand you manipulate vertical positions of the two images inside the node using the `adjustbox` package?

Comment: I am still interested in how the coordinate calculation works there, since the 'properly' parenthesized version still does break the compilation. 
I must be doing something wrong here...

Comment: @PaulMndn Yes, by using the `export` option of `adjustbox` the `valign` option becomes available for `\includegraphics`. There are other ways to top align the two images, but this is the easy way.